# Measure final ImageView width in GridView row

Tags: android, gridview

When adding an ImageView to a GridView item (Adapter), I would like to know the final width of the ImageView as it is rendered on the screen, so I can adapt the TextView to the exact size of the ImageView. However, when adding the ImageView as GridView item, based on the available width of the GridView the ImageView will get resized/scaled and positioned with additional padding/ margin.

example:

[image: gridview]

The text is suppose to only overlay the ImageView and not span the full width of the container.

The above image is rendered as followed:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<net.ninefigures.caspertv.widget.SizeAwareImageView
    android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mqdefault"/>

<net.ninefigures.caspertv.widget.SourceSansProTextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/preview"
    android:text="Lorum Ipsum Dolor Sit Amit"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Tried measuring the ImageView width in the getView of the Grid Item with the following:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    final TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    final ImageView thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = thumbnail.getViewTreeObserver();
        if(viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
            viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = thumbnail.getViewTreeObserver();

                    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            viewTreeObserver.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            viewTreeObserver.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("MeasuredHeight:  %d", thumbnail.getHeight()));
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("MeasuredWidth:  %d", thumbnail.getWidth()));
                }
            });
        }
```

However, this always returns 0;

Any ideas on how to measure the final width of the ImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the trick is to explicitly measure the width/height of the ImageView prior to rendering.

```
thumbnail.measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
title.setWidth(thumbnail.getMeasuredWidth());
```

Answer (score 0):

try inside

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```

it will be called after your view is rendered.